# How to retrieve position history in SAP SuccessFactors API via OData

Tags: odata, sap-successfactors

I'm extracting data from SAP `SuccessFactors` via OData API.

I need the status history of a Position entity, i.e. how and when the position's status had been changed.

Unfortunately, I can not find any documentation about it and it looks like I can not extract this data.

Do you know if there is such information and how I can extract it?